# Maintaing Images when switching servers

Tags: nodes, media

I just changed the server one of my sites is hosted on. In doing so, I lost all the images. The CCK file upload fields show "ghost" data but contain no actual image data as they did before the site transfer.
All my data is fine, however.

Is there a way to prevent this so all my images are maintained?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What module are you using to upload/show images? CCK + ImageField?

Anyways, to troubleshot your problem you need to figure the reason why no images are shown. This can be due to several reasons:

1. Wrong file Permission. When uploading via FTP or CPanel sometimes sometimes file permission gets messed. Try setting permission to 777 recursively to your image folder and see if images appear.
2. different absolute path. Some modules use an absolute path to figure in which folder they should upload images to. one easy way to find out is to create/upload a new image via CKK and using firebug (for instance) compare the URI of old images to the URI of the new image.

Keep us posted

Comment: Thanks Tivie, I do use CCK + Imagefield.
I will look into the file permissions asap - that's something I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Sooo, what was the answer?